# How to check status of profile synchronization service using C#

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, profile-sync

How to check status of profile synchronization service using C#,
 Can we do this using C#.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach (SPService srv in SPFarm.Local.Services)
{
    if (srv.Name.Equals("profile synchronization service name"))
    {
        foreach (SPServiceApplication srvApp in srv.Applications)
        {
           var status = srvApp.Status;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also check all SPServiceApplication members [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spserviceapplication_members.aspx)

Comment: Please, that kind of comment is not needed on all of your answers. Give users some time to test and verify your solution before posting a reminder-comment

Comment: Thanks M.Qassas , Let me try with this.. I will let you know the thing i will do.

Comment: Dear @G.Srinivas takes your time my bro, I hope it helps you. I also here if you need any help or clarification :)